# Why is discord timing out when pressing discord.ui,button?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am currently working on creating an educational casino server in which a user can interact with my bot to play blackjack, slots, and roulette. I have the welcome channel set up so that when a user types /button_roles a message is sent and gives the user the option to choose three buttons, which assigns them a role to access a text channel. Currently, this times out giving the error:

> "The application did not respond"

and does not work assign a role to a user. Help!

```
import sys
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import discord.ui
from blackjack import Blackjack
import asyncio  # Import asyncio module

games = {}
intents = discord.Intents.all()
general_channel_id = xxx
welcome_channel_id = xxx
blackjack_channel_id = xxx  # Replace this with the ID of the blackjack channel.
roulette_channel_id = xxx  # replace with roulette channel ID
slots_channel_id = xxx # replace with slots channel ID
botToken = "PRIVATE"

sys.stdout.flush()

class CasinoBot(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.welcome_msg_id = None
class SelfRoles(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(timeout=None)

    """Assigns the black_jack role to a user"""

    @discord.ui.button(label='Blackjack', style=discord.ButtonStyle.gray)
    async def blackjack_assignment(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        await interaction.response.send_message("Button pressed!")
        blackjack_role = discord.utils.get(interaction.guild.roles, name="black_jack")
        await interaction.response.send_message(f"Role retrieved: {blackjack_role}")
        if not blackjack_role:
            await interaction.response.send_message("Error: Could not find the blackjack role.")
            return

        try:
            await interaction.member.add_roles(blackjack_role)
            await interaction.response.send_message("Role assigned!")
        except Exception as e:
            await interaction.response.send_message(f"Error: {e}")

    """Assigns the slots role to a user"""
    @discord.ui.button(label='Slots', style=discord.ButtonStyle.red)
    async def slots_assignment(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        slots_role = discord.utils.get(interaction.guild.roles, name="slots")
        if not slots_role:
            await interaction.response.send_message("Error: Could not find the slots role.")
            return

        try:
            await interaction.member.add_roles(slots_role)
            await interaction.response.send_message("Role assigned!")
        except Exception as e:
            await interaction.response.send_message(f"Error: {e}")

    """Assigns the roulette role to a user"""
    @discord.ui.button(label='Roulette', style=discord.ButtonStyle.green)
    async def roulette_assignment(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        roulette_role = discord.utils.get(interaction.guild.roles, name="roulette")
        if not roulette_role:
            await interaction.response.send_message("Error: Could not find the Roulette role.")
            return

        try:
            await interaction.member.add_roles(roulette_role)
            await interaction.response.send_message("Role assigned!")
        except Exception as e:
            await interaction.response.send_message(f"Error: {e}")

async def run_bot(welcome_msg_id):
    bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
    bot.add_cog(CasinoBot(bot))


    """Displays the three buttons to assign a role to a user, black_jack, slots, and roulette
        Made this change because it is easier than doing reactions
    """
    @bot.tree.command(name="button_roles", description="Displays buttons for users to assign the role they want to play games")
    async def button_roles(interaction: discord.Interaction):
        print("Command button_roles entered")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        await interaction.response.send_message(content="Welcome to the Educational Casino! Click a button to "
                                                        "direct yourself to a game channel!"
                                                        " Gray is Blackjack, Red is slots,"
                                                        "and green is roulette. Have fun!", view=SelfRoles())

    @bot.event
    async def on_ready():
        await bot.tree.sync()
        print("Bot is ready.")
        cog = bot.get_cog('CasinoBot')
        if cog:
            await cog.on_ready()
    @bot.event
    async def on_message(message):
        await bot.process_commands(message)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(run_bot(None))
```

I am expecting the bot to send a message to the welcome channel upon the command /button_roles being called, and a user to be able to click a button to assign their role.